# How to befriend a dog?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

A loading screen tip told me that by befriending a dog, it could show me some interesting things.

How do I do that?

If I shove myself into the dog for a while, hearts will show up, be it will stay there.

Are there ways to befriend a dog better than that?

Comment: Have you tried feeding it meat? (By holding it, the same way you feed horses Apples and Carrots)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the official guide of the game, it states that if you feed a dog three fruit or meat items it will lead you to a hidden chest in the area.

I also found this [link where it explains dog behavior and rewards](http://gameranx.com/features/id/96000/article/breath-of-the-wild-how-to-make-friends-with-dogs-get-rewards/).

> **How to Increase Bond With Dogs:**
>
> 1. Stand near a dog. Just face a dog and look at it — a puff of pink
>      will appear. That’s the first step in any doggy interaction.
> 2. Give the dog food! It doesn’t seem to matter what type of food —
>      though the quality will increase the bond. To give a dog food, open
>      your inventory and select “Hold”, then drop the food on the ground
>      near the dog. If the dog sees you drop the food in front of its
>      face, you’ll increase your bond.
> 3. [Unconfirmed] Run! After increasing bond, the dog will follow you
>      around. Do some sprinting with the dog and let it chase you.
> 4. [Unconfirmed] Play fetch. Use any wooden branch cut from a tree and
>      throw it while the dog is paying attention. It will run off and
>      retrieve the stick right away.

I can confirm the 3rd one works, but I've never tried to play fetch with the dog.

**Edit:**

After a coupel hours of testing and rising friendship with a dog I was not able to reproduce the fetch functionality. And confirmed that the official guide doesn't mention it so I would proced to assume it's not actually in the game.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you cannot play fetch.

Comment: I also jump around and at dogs, it seems to increase the bond level periodically.

Comment: @Fatalize Maybe we need to increase bond with the dog to certain level before he wants to play. I'll test it when I got enough time.

Comment: @Fatalize I second that dogs do not react to throwing branches. They rather bark at you if you accidentally hit them.