# Can I pet dogs?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Zelda Breath of the Wild you find dogs around stables and other various locations and when you feed them, they bring you to a chest.

I know that I can give it food and play with it but I want to show my appreciation for this by petting it. How does he know that he is a good boy if I can't pet him?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to befriend a dog?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303091/how-to-befriend-a-dog)

Comment: If you can't pet the dog to let him know he was a good boy just try shouting, "YOU'RE A GOOD BOY!" at your screen.

Comment: I tried that but my roommates got mad at me last night around 5 A.M. I feel like I could do more.

Comment: They're good dogs bront

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't actually pet a dog from what I've found.  However, there is a sort of glitch (if you will) that kind of looks like it.

See this [linked video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bwS9BzuNns). First, you have to unequip any items you are holding.  Then, use the attack button to attempt to draw a weapon out.  If you angle it right, it can appear that you are petting the dog.  In the video, the affection level actually increases as shown by the bubble effect produced by the dog when doing this.

There is actually a rather [humorous guide](http://www.shacknews.com/article/99335/zelda-breath-of-the-wild---how-to-pet-a-dog) on how to do this as well.

Comment: Love that guide! I think this answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you don't have to do anything to get the hearts from "petting" the dog, just standing near it/it's head (not sure if that's important) long enough will cause the hearts to appear once.  I always assumed this was the equivalent of letting the dog sniff you or petting the dog.

Comment: This isn't a glitch, and the "bubble effect" is simply a coincidence, as it only appeared because Link was standing next to it for long enough.