# Can't identify this Breath of the Wild ability

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've spent over 100 hours playing Breath of the Wild, but I haven't been able to unlock this ability. I'm confused because I feel like I've learned and used all of the game's mechanics. What could I be missing?

[image: Ability Controls Screenshot]

**Can anyone identify this ability and explain how to unlock it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this GameFaqs topic](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75151566):

> Jump Attack. Talk to Steen in Kakariko Village at night. He's in front of the General Store.

Comment: Thanks! I found that most of the abilities unlock as soon as you perform them. I guess interacting with an NPC is required to unlock this one.

Comment: Too bad it's not an ability that allows you to pet a dog :P

Comment: @JoshB. [you can sort of pet dogs in the game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/306515/can-i-pet-dogs/306516#306516).  It just looks weird.